# Что означают в коде сайта мета-теги csrf-param и csrf-token?

Tags: csrf

Прочитала что csrf - это Вид атак на посетителей веб-сайтов, использующий недостатки протокола HTTP. Не могу понять, что означает когда в коде сайта эти теги прописаны? Это мне как посетителю сайта чем-то грозит или нет? Зачем эти теги там прописаны, не совсем понятно, как защита от такого рода атак или наоборот, чтобы мошеннические действия проделывать??

Answer (score 1):

> CSRF (англ. Сross Site Request Forgery — «межсайтовая подделка запроса», также известна как CSRF) — вид атак на посетителей веб-сайтов, использующий недостатки протокола HTTP. Если жертва заходит на сайт, созданный злоумышленником, от её лица тайно отправляется запрос на другой сервер (например, на сервер платёжной системы), осуществляющий некую вредоносную операцию (например, перевод денег на счёт злоумышленника). Для осуществления данной атаки жертва должна быть аутентифицирована на том сервере, на который отправляется запрос, и этот запрос не должен требовать какого-либо подтверждения со стороны пользователя, которое не может быть проигнорировано или подделано атакующим скриптом. [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

Это текстовые строки которые позволяют избежать атаки

Comment: Определение CSRF я знаю, спасибо. Вопрос в том, опасно ли это для меня? Правильно ли я понимаю, что эти строки владелец сайта прописал, чтобы предотвратить CSRF-атаку на свой сайт?

Comment: "Это текстовые строки которые позволяют избежать атаки"